# EF - Saving data to DB through Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am a little confused,I hope you can help.
I try to save my data into my database,which has multiple tables and I wanna reach them through my
navigation properties.But when i try to save the data,I get null reference  exception (It says my object reference didn't set for any object - I hope I wrote it well,my VS threw it as hungarian).
I tried it on 2 different ways.

...

.cs:

```
        Mentett mentett = new Mentett(); //reaching Mentett table through mentett
        KiesoIdo kiesoido= new KiesoIdo();
```

When I do I get a null reference exception,It says my object reference didn't set for any object. When I do my 1st try,It says the same and sometimes the Insert statement conflicts with a foreign key I didn't even use in the Inner Exception. I can't understand What is wrong,please help me :(

Comment: Where do you get exactly the exception?
What is KiesoIdo? Is it an object? If yes, you have to create it first. I don't know if you initialize it in constructor of Mentett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is an Entity Framework error.
Else you would get a ValidationError.
it is more likely, that one of your property objects is not initialized and
you get a NullReferenceException with
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

E.g. is KiesoIdo initialialized?
Try to put under the line

```
Mentett mentett = new Mentett();
```

the following line:

```
mentett.KiesoIdo = new KiesoIdo();
```

To analyze the validation errors, add a try-catch statement around your SaveAllChanges()

```
try
{ ... }
catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
{
  foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationErrors in exception.EntityValidationErrors)
  {
    foreach (DbValidationError validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
    {
      string log = string.Format("{0} - {1}",
      validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: KiesoIdo is one of my table and is created as :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KiesoIdo] (
    [KiesoID] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Rovidites]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Megnevezes]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KiesoID] ASC)
); Of course I put it's foreign key to Mentett table also. And it is filled with data,so I don't know what's wrong.... I get the exception on Mentett.KiesoIdo.Kieso row,when I try to save it.

Comment: When you debug, at what line do you get the exception?
Is mentett.KiesoIdo null?
You have to initialize it with mentett.KiesoIdo = new MyKiesoIdoClass()

Comment: All of KiesoIdo's attributes set to NOT NULL,but in the exception it wrote null on 1 line. And what to put MyKiesoIdoClass();

Comment: Try to put under the line Mentett mentett = new Mentett(); 
the following line: mentett.KiesoIdo = new KiesoIdo();
You create here a new object, that will be added later on with 
adatbazis.Mentett.Add() to you db context. Here it is just an object with an empty property KiesoIdo

Comment: It is worked what u said,but now on the SaveChanges line I get the following exception: {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} Inside ValidationErrors Count=1 ,{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}. And it wrote null to InnerException line.

Screenshot:

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/141008/validationerror_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png

Comment: I adapted the answer. The string "log" will tell you the error

Comment: Wow it works,you are right. It says,the PropertyName is the Rovidites attribute in my KiesoIdo table,and the Errormessage: you must add the following field : Rovidites (I translated it from Hun to Eng,dunno if it's correct). I don't understand,I didn't even use Rovidites in this part of program....It is only for one of my DataGrid. :( Any opinion? P.S.: The parameters of Rovidites is in one of my last comment,when i showed my create table. I use that table still. Not null can cause the problem?

Comment: Yes, either make it nullable or set it.

Comment: I am new in here,don't have enough reputation yet for that :-/ I hope I can do it soon:)