# Saving data to multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to save Data to 2 tables in my database. I can access my database and save data to one table.
But with 2 it doesn't work anymore. I think this is because the data comes from one form but the data is split into two parts: a form and one or more table rows both have to be filled from the user.

This is my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult saveIndex(VersandformularModel xModel)
    {
        using (var ctx = new Versandformular_DEVEntities())
        {
            Formular lFormular = new Formular();
            {
                lFormular.Absender_Firma = xModel.ccFirma[0];
                lFormular.Ansprechpartner = xModel.ccAnsprechpartner;


                lFormular.Empfänger_Firma = xModel.ccEmpfängerFirma;
                lFormular.Empfänger_Name = xModel.ccVorname + xModel.ccNachname;
                lFormular.Empfänger_Straße = xModel.ccStraße;
                lFormular.Empfänger_Land = xModel.ccLand;
                lFormular.Empfänger_PLZ_Ort = xModel.ccPLZ;
                lFormular.Empfänger_Bundesstaat = xModel.ccBundesstaat[0];
                lFormular.Empfänger_Telefon = xModel.ccTelefonNr;

                lFormular.Paketdienst = xModel.ccPaketdienst[0];
                lFormular.Versand_Bemerkung = xModel.ccBemerkungVersand;
                lFormular.Nächste_Lieferung = xModel.ccNächsteLieferung;
                lFormular.Warenkosten = xModel.ccWarenkosten;
                lFormular.Versandkosten = xModel.ccVersandkosten;
                lFormular.Kostenstelle = xModel.ccKostenstelle;

            };
            ctx.Formular.Add(lFormular);

            Artikel lArtikel = new Artikel();
            {
                foreach (var iiArtikel in xModel.ccTabelle)
                {
                    lArtikel.ArtikelNr = iiArtikel.ccArtikelNr;
                    lArtikel.WarentarifNr = iiArtikel.ccWarentarifNr;
                    lArtikel.Anzahl = iiArtikel.ccAnzahl;
                    lArtikel.Einzelpreis = iiArtikel.ccEinzelpreis;
                    lArtikel.Gesamtpreis = iiArtikel.ccAnzahl * iiArtikel.ccEinzelpreis;
                    lArtikel.Anzahl_Pakete = iiArtikel.ccAnzahlPakete;
                    lArtikel.Fertig_verpackt = iiArtikel.ccFertigVerpackt;
                    lArtikel.Inhaltsbeschreibung = iiArtikel.ccInhaltsbeschreibung;
                    lArtikel.Inhalt_Bemerkung = iiArtikel.ccBemerkungInhalt;

                    ctx.Artikel.Add(lArtikel);
                }

            }




            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Content("Hallo Welt");
    }
```

when im sending the data I always get a DbEntityValidationException

here the entities:

```
namespace Versandformular.Entity
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Versandformular_DEVEntities : DbContext
    {
        public Versandformular_DEVEntities()
            : base("name=Versandformular_DEVEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Artikel> Artikel { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Formular> Formular { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for the entities? The exception you get is caused by validation rules, so we need to be able to see the relevant code.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the error but you are adding the same `Artikel` multiple times to the context. You should move `Artikel lArtikel = new Artikel();` inside of the `foreach`

Comment: @Rhumborl just tried it and didnt work ... thanks anyway

Comment: what are the errors in DbEntityValidationException?
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26234574/2707156 how to get the messages.

Comment: Sorry FlowX, I meant the actual entities (e.g. `Artikel` and `Formular`), not the EntityContext.

Comment: It said some fields have to be filled. I wanted to fill those fields later based on some input but now i gave them a placeholder and now it works fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @elolos I found my mistake, look at my comment above :) thanks anywany :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override **SaveChanges** to find improved validation message of DbEntityValidationException.

1.Create a new partial class in the same location as where your EDMX resides.

2.Use the following piece of C# code to override the SaveChanges implementation.

```
public partial class NorthwindEntities
{
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
        var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

        // Join the list to a single string.
        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

        // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
        var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

        // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
}
}
```

Refer this link for more details :
http://devillers.nl/improving-dbentityvalidationexception/